# state on a non-unital $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $\tau$ is a state on a non-unital $C^*$ algebra $A$.There is a well-known inequality:
$$\tag{$*$}|\tau(a)|^2\leq\tau(a^*a),\ \text{ for all } a\in A.$$

1. Does there exist some  nonzero element $a_0$ such that $\tau(a_0^*a_0)-|\tau(a_0)|^2$ is small enough?
2. Does there exist a nonzero elements $a_0$ such that equality holds in $(*)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any state and any approximate unit $\{e_j\}$ of $A$, you have $\lim_j\tau(e_j)=\|\tau\|$ (cfr. Davidson's C$^*$-Algebras by Example, Lemma I.9.5). So here $\tau(e_j)\to1$. Since one can take $e_j\geq0$ and $\|e_j\|\leq1$ for all $j$, you have 
$$
\tau(e_j^*e_j)=\tau(e_j^2)\leq\|e_j\|\,\tau(e_j)\leq1. 
$$
Thus
$$
1=\lim_j|\tau(e_j)|^2\leq\limsup_j\tau(e_j^*a_j)\leq1,
$$
giving us equality. This gives the existence of your $a_0$.

The answer to your second question is no when $\tau$ is faithful. Given your $\tau$, you can always extend it to the unitization $\tilde A$ of $A$, and the extension is still faithful. So if $\|a\|\leq1$ and $|\tau(a)|^2=\tau(a^*a)$, this is equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, so you get that $a=\lambda\,1$.

When $\tau$ is not faithful, equality can occur. For instance take $A=M_2(\mathbb C)\oplus K(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$, and $\tau(a\oplus k)=a_{22}$. Then the matrix unit $E_{22}\oplus 0$ satisfies the equality

Comment: For any $\epsilon > 0$,there exists $e_0$(depends on $\epsilon$) such that $\tau(e_0^*e_0)-|\tau(e_0)|^2＜\epsilon$.For different  $\epsilon $s ,we have different $e_0$s,But I want to find a fixed constant ,the answer is no if $\tau$ is faithful.Thanks,Pro Argerami!

Comment: If $\tau$ is not faithful,does there must exist $a$ such that the equality holds?

Comment: Yes. If $\tau$ is not faithful, there exists $b\geq0$ with $\tau(b)=0$. Take $a=b^{1/2}$, and then $\tau(a^*a)=0$.

Comment: Can $\tau(a^*a)=|\tau(a)|^2$= nonzero positive number if $\tau $ is not faithful.

Comment: Yes. There is an example in the answer.

Comment: I mean whether there must exist a nonzero element $a$ such that $\tau(a^*a)=|\tau(a)|^2$= positive real number if $\tau$ is not faithful

Comment: No. Take $\tau$ faithful on $A$, and extend trivially to $A\oplus 0$.

Comment: I'm not following.I assume that $\tau$ is not faithful on A,but you take $\tau$ is faithful on A.

Comment: Yes, but then $\tilde\tau(a\oplus 0)=\tau(a)$ is not faithful.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question about the $a$'s for which $$\tau(a^\ast a) = |\tau(a)|^2$$: It seems that it can be solved using Choi's Theorem on multiplicative domains of cp maps, see [BO; Proposition 1.5.7]. In particular $a$ satisfies the identity above iff for every $b \in A$, $\tau(b a) = \tau(b) \tau(a) = \tau(a) \tau(b) = \tau(a b)$.

[BO] *Brown, Nathanial P.; Ozawa, Narutaka*, $C^*$-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations, Graduate Studies in Mathematics 88. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xv, 509 p. (2008). [ZBL1160.46001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1160.46001).

Comment: Would you pleasae tell me the details, the proposition is true for c.c.p. maps,but here $\tau$ is a state.How to  apply Choi's thorem?

Comment: Any state is completely positive (the GNS construction basically gives you a factorization $V^\ast \pi(a) V$)